# How do I store serialize an NSDictionary with NSJSONSerialization when one of the values is NSData?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

Take this simplified example:

```
let dict: [String: AnyObject] = ["foo": ("bar" as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!9]

let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: [])
```

I cannot get that to run, it crashes with:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSConcreteMutableData)'

I need to send a block of JSON to my server, where some values are strings and some are `NSData`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It's worth your time to read through the [JSON RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). Note:

> JSON can represent four primitive types (strings, numbers, booleans, and null) and two structured types (objects and arrays).

JSON can't represent raw data, so you'll need to convert the `NSData` to one of those other types (typically a string). One common approach is:

```
let stringFromData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Just make sure you and your server agree on which encoding you'll use.

If you have a lot of these, you can map through your dictionary and convert them at once. There are a few possible implementations depending on your structure; here's one approach:

```
let dictWithString = dict.map { (key, value) -> (String, NSObject) in
    if let value = value as? NSData {
        return (key, NSString(data: value, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }

    return (key, value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your NSData into Base64 Encoded string in order to set to your json content.

```
let base64String = rawData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

and decoding:

```
let rawData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```